# Find $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x(1-\cos{x})}{\left(\tan{x}\right)^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x(1-\cos{x})}{\left(\tan{x}\right)^3}$$
I have got the answer to be 1/2. Is that correct, and is there any shortcut for the above problem.

Comment: Use $\tan x \sim x$.

Comment: I didn't get that.

Comment: In one line, using known limits: $$\frac{x(1 - \cos x)}{\tan^3 x} = \left( \frac{\tan x}{ x} \right)^{-1} \frac{1- \cos x}{x^2} \left( \frac{\tan x}{x} \right)^{-2} \to 1^{-1} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1^{-2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Wow that's an awesome shortcut! I used complicated differentiation and things for this while u did this so simply. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{x(1-\cos x)}{\tan^3x}=\frac x{\tan x}\cdot\frac{\sin^2x}{(1+\cos x)\tan^2x}=\frac x{\tan x}\cdot\frac{\cos^2x}{1+\cos x}\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}1\cdot\frac12=\frac12$$

Comment: Well u used rationalisation. Awesome. I could have done that!

Comment: @LokeshSangewar Once you see it you'll hardly forget it. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah! Cheers! ;-)    ^_^

Answer (score 0):

It is not complicated if you use equivalents $$\cos(x)\sim 1-\frac{x^2}2$$ $$\tan(x)\sim x$$ from which you can easily conclude.

Comment: And how do we get those equivalents?

Comment: @LokeshSangewar. I supposed you knew them. They are pretty standard and very often used in limits.

Comment: Nope I don't know them. I am still a class 10 student so I guess I don't know what r they. Please help me

Comment: @LokeshSangewar These are Taylor approximations. Look up Taylor series for these functions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  well I haven't used these equivalents anywhere till now, so maybe if u tell me, iwill be able to solve problems a bit quicker.

Comment: @MrYouMath well I looked it up in wolfram only to be confused more.